# SCoverage + Jenkins: graph trend shows 0%, xml report is correct

Tags: jenkins, scoverage

I'm using scoverage plugin for jenkins. It successfully copies generated .xml and .html files to the build directory. But on the project main page the graph shows 0% coverage.

Here is the image: [0% coverage on main page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IqJd.png)

Any ideas why? Thanks!